# How to select a submatrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, subtraction, matrix-indexing

Hello and happy new year!

I have a problem, and I can't find a solution.

I need to create these 2 matrices, `C` from `B` with submatrix.

```
B = [  1   2   3   4   5   6   7 
       9   7   5   3   1  -1  -3 
       4   8  16  32  64 128 256];
```

And I want to extract this matrix from it:

```
C = [  2   3   4   5
      32  64 128 256]
```

First I created the matrix `B`:

```
B = (1:7; 9:-2:-3; 2.^(2:8));
```

But with this I get an error:

```
C = B([1,(2:5)]; [3,(4:7)]);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just a grammar issue.

Just try this:

```
C = [B(1, 2:5); B(3, 4:7)];
```

Comment: Thank you...! I am new in Matlab and i lost 1 hour for this!!